# Android Fragment Reverse Animations Not Working

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I am developing the tablet portion of my application that incorporates a Master-Detail Flow Template. When I click a button on the detail side, a fragment transition animation takes place on that side with one fragment replacing the other with:

```
MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_push_left_in, R.anim.abc_push_left_out,
     R.anim.abc_push_right_out, R.anim.abc_push_right_in);

transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

The animation in the transition works perfectly. However, when I want to go back to the previous fragment by clicking a back button, the fragment that's coming in appears with the push animation working, but the fragment that's leaving is not executing its exiting push animation. It's simply disappearing with only one animation working.

I've tried using different animations but I get the same result. Does anyone have an idea of what's happening or if I'm not understanding something about fragment transitions?

EDIT: My activity_skill_twopane.xml's detail FrameLayout is the fragment container with its id as R.id.main_fragment_container. It appears that when I put an ImageView in the detail FrameLayout in the xml it shows up in the background while the animations are happening as well. Does anyone know why that's happening too?

EDIT: My animation xml's are as follows:

abc_push_left_in:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

abc_push_left_out:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%" android:duration="500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

abc_push_right_in:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%" android:duration="500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

abc_push_right_out:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

UPDATE: I managed to recreate the problem on a handset. If you have one Fragment Activity with a button that does a fragment transaction with animations like mine and press back from the second activity to call "popBackStackImmediate", you will notice that the fragment being replaced just disappears without animating while the fragment that's replacing executes its animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it wrong, the null is only for the name, so you are adding it to the backstack already.

You should have the animations in a different order like this:

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_push_left_in, R.anim.abc_push_left_out,
 R.anim.abc_push_right_in, R.anim.abc_push_right_out);
```

Also you don't need to override onBackPressed the system should handle it for you.

Comment: In all the fragment transactions in my app I do transaction.addToBackStack(null);. Are you saying I should put it somewhere else? The back button in my app calls getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

Comment: This helps a bit, but even with this code, the fragment that's being replaced is quickly disappearing without any animation while the fragment that's replacing it is executing its animation like it should. Weird how only one part is working.

Comment: Please post your animations

Comment: these animation work perfectly on the phone part of my app, but the difference is that I'm working with activity transitions in the phone part

Comment: I'm curious what's the problem! :D I tested what you wrote: so the animations where in the right order like you wrote it originally, you should only switch the names, so it fits the description. It works for me like a charm, push in push out. Can you post your code with your activity and fragments, and layouts to git, so I can take a look?

Comment: thanks for your help, but I simply recreated the fragments and it started working for me. I do not know why this worked, but it did. First I created a new simple project with fragment activity and fragments for handsets and it worked. Then, I just simply recreated my fragments in format of google's way of doing it from this url: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html.